# Why does my Android Phone open multiple Hotspots?

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot, windows

When I turn on my mobile hotspot on a Samsung phone in 5Ghz preferred mode without autohotspot, my Windows laptop lists multiple hotspots that are numbered, for example:

- "Hotspotname"
- "Hotspotname 2"
- "Hotspotname 3"

Sometimes I cannot connect to the internet using one of these while the others still work. What are these different networks and which should I connect to?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There was a similar question [What is the number behind tethering Wi-Fi name on Windows and how to reset it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/240955/44325) that was migrated to Super User because it was assumed that the issue is with how Windows detects the hotspot instead of the Android's behavior.

Comment: Indeed, it is essentially the same question and was (more or less) answered in https://superuser.com/questions/1520024/why-does-my-wifi-name-show-up-as-wifi-name-number